# Issue in regard to installation of Tuxboot 0.7 to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

Installed Tuxboot. When I clicked on the icon, Tuxboot 0.7 window shows up but nothing in the window. Could you please help to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 tuxboot
```

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1620628